# How can you reach your labyrinth while in the Bloom?

Tags: torment-tides-of-numenera

Is there any way to reliably reach your labyrinth in this part of the game (i.e. like the mirror or Tranquility in Sagus Cliffs)? I've explored all the areas I can currently access (courtyard, interior and the three slums) and have several quests I need to finish in my labyrinth, but I can't find an easy way to reach it while in the Bloom.

Minor spoiler:

> I already defeated Waits-for-prey, so this is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are one option:

Drink from pools of Bloom juice twice

There is a dialogue option with Waits-for-prey to kill you, but it will refuse to do so when asked.

Comment: Only option 1 works though, unless you count fighting and dying vs waits-for-prey. The dialog option simply causes it to state, that it will not kill you.